# Magento 2: How to get product url in order email

Tags: magento2, email-templates, sales

I am trying to get the product url along with product name in

`app/design/frontend/yourPackage/yourtemplate/template/email/order/items/order/default.phtml`

Here is the code that gets the product name and sku. Is there any function that can return the product url to be used in the email as a clickable link?

```
<p class="product-name"><?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?></p>
<p class="sku"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('SKU'); ?>: <?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getSku($_item)) ?></p>
```

Comment: How about your issue?

Answer (score 3):

You try with :

```
<?php /** @var $block \Magento\Bundle\Block\Sales\Order\Items\Renderer */ ?>
<?php $_item = $block->getItem() ?>
<?php $product_url= $_item->getProduct()->getProductUrl(); // Our code here?>
```

Comment: In the template file at the top there is

Comment: In the template file at the top there is
$_item = $block->getItem();
so should i try with
<p class="product-name"><a href="<?= $_item->getProduct()->getProductUrl(); ?>">
<?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?></a></p>

Comment: Don't need to add the top, you can use inside the template.